# Compare two list of sets

Tags: python, list

For example, I have two list of sets:

```
list1 = [{'a','b'}, {'c','d'}, {'a','b','c'}, {'c','f'}]
list2 = [{'c','d','e'}, {'e','f'}, {'a','b','d'}, {'c','f'}]
```

I need to output a list of indices where list1[i] and list2[i] don't share common elements. (no intersection)

In this case, `{'a','b'}` has no common elements in `{'c','d','e'}`.

1. `{'c','d'}` has no common elements in `{'e','f'}`.
2. `{'a','b','c'}` has common elements `'a'` and `'b'` in `{'a','b','d'}`.
3. `{'c','f'}` has common elements `'c'` and `'f'` in `{'c','f'}`.

So `list1[0]` and `list1[1]` do not have the same element(s) in `list2[0]` and `list2[1]`

It will return a list of indices: `list = [0,1]`

My approach is:

```py
for l1,l2 in zip(list1,list2):
    for i in l1:
        if i in l2:
            print(i)
```

This is clearly not correct. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Apparently you already know how to compare elements from the lists pairwise, so the *actual question* is about how to check whether two sets have elements in common. (Or is it about how to get the indices for the compared pairs? You can get those the same way you would when iterating over a plain list: using `enumerate`.) The elements that two sets have in common are called the *intersection* of those sets; and sets that do not have common elements are called *disjoint*. Knowing the terminology, it becomes easy to [research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can enumerate over the zipped lists and filter the indices based on whether the pair of sets [is disjoint](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.isdisjoint):

```
list1 = [{'a','b'}, {'c','d'}, {'a','b','c'}, {'c','f'}]
list2 = [{'c','d','e'}, {'e','f'}, {'a','b','d'}, {'c','f'}]

indices = [i for i, (a, b) in enumerate(zip(list1, list2)) if a.isdisjoint(b)]

# [0, 1]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I need to get more familiar with operators.

Comment: itertools version: `indices = list(compress(count(), map(set.isdisjoint, list1, list2)))`

Comment: That’s really nice @KellyBundy. I don’t see `map()` used like that with multiple iterables very often. Works well here.

Comment: Yes, seems almost as rare/unknown as compress. I like pointing both out :-)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, I'm using a dictionary to output the common letters for each set

```
iter = [i for i in range(len(list1))]
list3 = []
dict = {}
for i in iter:
    for l1, l2 in zip(list1[i], list2[i]):
        letter = ""
        if l1 not in list2[i]:
            letter += l1
        if l2 not in list1[i]:
            letter += l2
        if letter != '':
        dict[f'Index  {str(i)}'] = letter
print(dict)
```